Не работает градиент в SVG (через use)
Гайс, столкнулся с проблемой, на ноутбуке и планшете (андроид) градиенты в svg отображаються прилично, а на айфоне уже не работают, может кто знает что это может быть? может там какой то медиазапрос нужно писать или полифил какой то на фикс?


Уже не знаю сколько я сижу в поисках решения, и мне нужна помощь
Что делаю на сайте необычного? та ничего стандартный код, html, css(scss), js, собираю gulp, то есть ничего такого что могло бы вызвать такие проблемы, но я в отчаянии :

Код сюда нужно а не на гитхаб...каким образом присваивали градиент?

@РезидентКазахстана Галп сгенерировал за меня спрайт, а в спрайтах свг лежит с градиентом в теге symbol, а я его никак сам не задавал, скачал с фигмы забросил в сборку, получился спрайт, от туда и использовал

Попробуйте, не через symbol присвоить градиент а через fill
